# How to convert integer into hexadecimal wstring in C++

Tags: c++, hex

How to convert integer into hexadecimal std::wstring in C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same as a narrow string:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

//...

std::wostringstream oss;  // note the 'w'
oss << std::hex << n;

return oss.str();         // type is std::wstring
```